# Autocomplete Jquery UI dosen't work_ASP.net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I want to use `Autocomplete UI` for a search box 
this is my head tag in Layout

```
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/myjs.js"></script>
```

and this is my text box in view

```
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input type="text" id="tags">
```

and here is  my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];


    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
```

but it dosen't show anything after typing... Appreciate if help me thanks

Comment: Make sure that all files are included, there is no thing wrong with the code [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o40nefvs/1/)

Comment: thanks for care , I checked many times. I  have no idea whats the problem unfortunately.

Comment: Does the page have any autopost back asp feature refreshing the page? Does asp generate a different id for the element?

Comment: @TJ It solved some one helped me but there is no comments and answer here  . the problem was the version of jquery and jquery UI. but I don't know what happend to the answer . anyway thanks for your care .

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the version of `jquery` and `jquery UI` which I included. now it solved